# How can I use the python idle colours with a non-python file extension

Tags: python-3.x, python-idle

I am currently using a custom file extension in the python idle editor (.ape), but when I open it with the standard IDLE editor, it doesn't show the colours, everything is just black on white. So there a way of opening a non-python extension in the IDLE editor, and still have the colours?

Sorry if this isn't the right place to ask, but I have no idea where else to ask.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you mean syntax coloring, and that your .ape files contain Python code.  IDLE currently does not have a way to override file extensions.  There is a request somewhere on the Python tracker to be able to turn syntax highlighting on for cases where python code is embedded in another file (.txt, .html, .rst, etc).  Such an option would also solve your problem.

On Windows, Notepad++ will apparently apply any language highlighting scheme it knows (about 50) to any file.  It is not as nice, though, for running edited code.

Comment: Thanks, Syntax colouring is what I meant, with python code in the .ape files. I have had a go at using notepad++ but, like you said, I found it too difficult to run the code.